# Magento2 after created category WHOOPS, OUR BAD

Tags: magento2.3.7

looking for fix the error after created the category and the category display in home page and after click on category to show page category i get this error

WHOOPS, OUR BAD...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with category URL Rewrites. Please do the re-index if you haven't done already.

Do the followings:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

And clear the browser cache as well and check the result.

Comment: I did that and there is no solution

Comment: @Nino Still the same problem? Could you provide the Search Engine Optimization URL you provide for the newly created category? I mean the category URL? If it has a forward slash at the end, please remove it, do re-index, clear cache and try again.